# How to filter a redirection within -exec into a find command?

Tags: shell, grep, tar

I googled and read a lot of blogs, never find this sort of question.
I got a script, compress.sh, which is called via a cronjob. The cronjob executes well, and send a mail to *root* which is wrapped to my personnal email.

I receive a lot of :

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

Two solutions and two questions !

**FIRST WAY**, in the command :

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -path '*/\.*' -type d -exec tar czf {}_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).tar.gz {} \;
```

I know where to place the "-C /" parameter, but I ignore **how to cut the leading "/"** present in the "{}".

**SECOND WAY**, in the above command, **where to place** the `grep -v "tar : removing leading ..."`in order to filter and send the specific error message to /dev/null ?

Note that i'd prefer the first (the correct) way, but i wonder how to work with the second too.

NB : it is because I guess that if it is the only error message, once filtered, I will not receive a mail ... only if one other problem occurs.

Comment: You could simply avoid generating the warnings to begin with by doing `cd /; find dir1/dir2/dir3/ ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in the first way - you cannot directly process `{}`, but you can pass it as an argument to `bash`, and then process it as a positional parameter. So instead of:

```
-exec tar czf {}_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).tar.gz {} \;
```

You can use:

```
-exec bash -c 'tar czf "$0_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).tar.gz" -C / "${0#/}"' {} \;
```

Instead of using `-exec` to execute `tar` directly, a `bash` subshell is called, passing the `tar` command as the argument for the `-c` option. `{}` is passed as the first argument. This is then accessible inside the subshell as `$0`. `${0#/}` is a parameter expansion which removes a single slash from the start of `$0`.

To do it the second way, you must first redirect stderr so that you can use `grep -v` on it, then redirect it back to stderr so that any other error messages will be processed normally. You can add this to the end of your command:

```
find ... \; 2> >(grep -v "tar: Removing leading" >&2)
```

This redirects stderr into a process substitution, which then performs the `grep` command on the data and redirects it back to stderr - so any lines which `grep` matches will be removed, everything else will pass through unchanged.

Comment: As far as I knew, the "correct" way is a first one while the second calls grep each time a ligne is passed to stderr. Now, I wonder if the call to a subshell at each element of the list would not be much harder ... I'll do some tests in order to compare. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Well ! It is now done in the first way. I put $date in DATE, and then call "$0_$(echo -n $DATE) ... iot obtain the same timestamp for a loop of backup ...but it is not working ... I'll search on my own why ...

Answer (score 1):

**First way:**

You can use bash to remove the initial /.

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -path '*/\.*' -type d -exec bash -c 'a="{}" ; a=${a#/} ; tar czf $a_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).tar.gz $a' \;
```

**Second way:**

You can pipe standard error to grep and filter out the message you don't want.

```
blah |& grep -v "Removing leading"
```

Comment: Thak you VERY MUCH ooga ... I'd rather validate Josh Jolly because its answer is much more readable by other users. TY !